# how to make automatic update table based on python file

Tags: python, html

I have a python file that will be running all the time.
and I want to display the information from python file to a table on a webpage.
and I want to keep the table up to date.
in the python file, there is a loop, and for every loop iteration, I want to update the table.

how can I make this? which language should I use?

I am not the one who wrote the python file.

Comment: You gave us no information. You gave us no attempt. Please read the rules for this website before posting.

Comment: I didn't understand the question clearly but if the table is being updated from the python script, you can use meta's http-equiv to refresh document.

Answer (score 1):

[Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) is a very easy, Python based web tool for generating APIs and integrating Python scripts for output to a webpage.

Doing actual code for you here is probably too much to ask as a question, but I would recommend looking at the linked Flask tutorial.

Comment: thankyou for the link, I 'am not asking for the code, I just want some guide how to make it, it's because the first time for me work with python, I use to work with PHP

Comment: Simply put, you can create a model with flask which accepts variables using the [Jinja](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/) format. Your existing script can be called by the Flask `app`, which can then accept variables created by the existing script, and then those variables can be used to display the data in the page.